# How can I use images SVG in Angular with NativeScript?

Tags: angular, image, svg, nativescript

I have a problem when I want use images SVG in NativeScript with Angular. I did the typical where I used de tag: `<Image src="res://image.svg"></Image>` and `<Image src="~/images/image.svg"></Image>`. In NativeScript not show images in format SVG natively, the solution is use a plugin of Nativescript https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-svg, but this plug-in does not currently work (https://github.com/peoplewareDo/nativescript-svg/issues/24).
I only have images in SVG, I don't have others format of images .
What do I to resolve this problem?

Comment: If you are good with PNG / JPG, there are lot of tools online which can convert your image format still.

Answer (score 2):

After checking the provided issue on `nativescript-svg` GitHub, I do see some comments saying that [bradmartin fork](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-svg) is working for Android. Have you tried it?

Also, on the official NativeScript repo, there is a reopened issue regarding [svg support](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/944). So I would recommend saving your svgs files as `png/jpeg` or any other supported format in the meantime.

Cheers!

Comment: Crazy, as of now ( 2023 ) there's still no support for SVG ..